# Bash run a group of two children in the background and kill them later

Tags: linux, bash, shell, background-process

Let's group two commands (`cd` and `bash ..`) together like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

C="directory"
SH="bash process.sh"

(cd ${C}; ${SH})&
PID=$!
sleep 1
KILL=`kill ${PID}`
```

`process.sh` prints out the date (each second and five times):

```sh
C=0
while true
do
    date
    sleep 1
    if [ ${C} -eq 4 ]; then
        break
    fi
    C=$((C+1))
done
```

Now I actually would expect the background subprocess to be killed right after *1* second, but it just continues like nothing happens. INB4: "Why don't you just `bash directory/process.sh`" No, this `cd` is just an example.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't store code in variables. Functions store code, variables store data; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Also, note that all-caps variable names are used by the shell for variables that modify behavior of the shell itself, or are used to reflect its behavior, or which can modify behavior of POSIX-specified tools. By contrast, names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have unwanted side effects on POSIX-compliant shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec` when you want a process to replace itself in-place, rather than creating a new subprocess with its own PID.

That is to say, this code can create **two** subprocesses, storing the PID of the first one in `$!` but then using the second one to execute `process.sh`:

```
# store the subshell that runs cd in $!; not necessarily the shell that runs process.sh
# ...as the shell that runs cd is allowed to fork off a child and run process.sh there.
(cd "$dir" && bash process.sh) & pid=$!
```

...whereas this code creates *only one* subprocess, because it uses `exec` to make the first process replace itself with the second:

```
# explicitly replace the shell that runs cd with the one that runs process.sh
# so $! is guaranteed to have the right thing
(cd "$dir" && exec bash process.sh) &
```

Comment: Can we do : `(cd "$dir" && source process.sh) &` ? thus saving one `exec`

Comment: @Philippe, sure. Not going to be identical to running something in a new instance necessarily, though -- unexported functions, aliases, temporary `shopt` settings, etc. will survive, which may upset assumptions made by the author of the script.

Answer (score 0):

you can check all child processes with "ps --ppid $$"
so,

```
#!/bin/bash

C="directory"
SH="bash process.sh"

(cd ${C}; ${SH})&
PID=$!
sleep 1
ps -o pid= --ppid $$|xargs kill
```